# Static jQuery random numbers

Tags: jquery, html

I have managed to create a random number for an image when click. I don't know how to make the random number static(I mean not change every time I click the image unless I reload the page) here's the Code I am working with

```
    `  $("#crystal1").on("click", function() {
        crystalRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        $("#score-area").append(crystalRandomNumber);
    })`
```

Comment: You can use `one`, instead of `on`, and the event handler will only process at most one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that

```
 $("#crystal1").on("click", function() {

        var crystalRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

        if(!$(this).data('number')){

          $(this).data('number',crystalRandomNumber);

          $("#score-area").append(crystalRandomNumber);

        }

    })
```

Comment: what does !$ do?

Comment: ! is not logic operator and $ is Jquery instance the if condition means that : if number is undefined set it if exist don't make anything ;)